# How to add subtitles to video player with libvlc

Tags: python, libvlc

I can't add subtitles to video player

```
self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
self.player = self.Instance.media_player_new()

m = self.Instance.media_new(str(video))
self.player.set_media(m)
self.player.video_set_subtitle_file(str(self.mySub))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using `libvlc` version 2.2:

```py
import vlc
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('Test.avi')
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()  # ← your code doesn't have this
player.video_set_subtitle_file('Test.srt')
```

#### Using `libvlc` version 3:

- `player.video_set_subtitle_file()` is deprecated
- use `add_slave()`

```py
import vlc
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new('Test.avi')
Sub = player.add_slave(player,'Test.srt', True)

player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

- From [Python vlc library](http://qaru.site/questions/14529425/vlc-python-library)

#### Additionally:

- From [python-vlc/generated/3.0/vlc.py](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/generated/3.0/vlc.py)

```py
def video_set_subtitle_file(self, psz_subtitle):
    '''Set new video subtitle file.
    \deprecated Use L{add_slave}() instead.
    @param psz_subtitle: new video subtitle file.
    @return: the success status (boolean).
    '''
    return libvlc_video_set_subtitle_file(self, str_to_bytes(psz_subtitle))
```

Comment: No idea. Search for an existing answer, or add a new question.